# How can I get the results from 2 separate JavaFX Service threads?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

I'm New to javaFx so i might be missing something easy here but i cant seem to find this solution. I have a application that needs to execute two separate functions in parallel then needs to update the UI only when both have returned with the returned values. I have created some test code and seen below and every things works except the results. How can i get this to print the results of the thread execution. In my example the label should be display `thread1Result: false thread2Result: true` but it displays null for both.

Main class

```
public class Main extends Application {
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    launch( args );
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
 */
@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load( getClass().getResource( "/application/LoadPage.fxml" ) );
    Scene scene = new Scene( root );
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
}
```

LoadPage.fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
```

ControllerClass

```
public class Controller {
@FXML Label lbl_Status;
Boolean thread1Result = null;
Boolean thread2Result = null;

public void doIt(ActionEvent event){
    Button doitButton = ((Button) event.getSource() );
    doitButton.setDisable( true );
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    final ServiceExample service1 = new ServiceExample(4000);
    final ServiceExample service2 = new ServiceExample(5000);
    service1.setExecutor( es );
    service1.setOnSucceeded( new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle( WorkerStateEvent arg0 ) {
            thread1Result = service1.getValue();
        }
    });
    service2.setExecutor( es );
    service2.setOnSucceeded( new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle( WorkerStateEvent arg0 ) {
            thread2Result = service2.getValue();
        }
    });
    service1.start();
    service2.start();

    try {
        es.shutdown();
        es.awaitTermination( 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    doitButton.setDisable( false );
    lbl_Status.setText( "thread1Result: " +  thread1Result + "  thread2Result: " + thread2Result );} }
```

ServiceExample Class

```
public class ServiceExample extends Service<Boolean> {
private int waitTime;
   public ServiceExample( int waitTime ) {
      this.waitTime = waitTime;
   }
   @Override
   protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
       return new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            if(waitTime >= 5000){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
      };
     }}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `service2.setOnSucceeded(...)` twice. The first one should presumably be `service1.setOnSucceeded(...)`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks James that was a copy past error i have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call

```
es.awaitTermination( 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
```

is a blocking call, so you should not perform it on the FX Application Thread as it will make the UI unresponsive.

The `state` property of a `Service` will be `SUCCEEDED` when the service's task completes. So you can do the following:

```
private BooleanBinding done ;

public void doIt(ActionEvent event){
    Button doitButton = ((Button) event.getSource() );
    doitButton.setDisable( true );
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    final ServiceExample service1 = new ServiceExample(4000);
    final ServiceExample service2 = new ServiceExample(5000);
    service1.setExecutor( es );
    service2.setExecutor( es );

   done = 
        service1.stateProperty().isEqualTo(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
        .and(service2.stateProperty().isEqualTo(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED));

    done.addListener((obs, wasDone, isNowDone) -> {
        if (isNowDone.booleanValue()) {
            lbl_Status.setText( "thread1Result: " +  service1.getValue() + "thread2Result: " + service2.getValue() );
            doitButton.setDisable(false);
        }
    });

    service1.start();
    service2.start();
}
```

Comment: This example code worked fine for me but when I replaced the `ThreadSleep()` function with the actual long running function the call back function never executed. The solution was to move the `BooleanBinding done` to a class scope. I suspect when the `doIt()` function completed `BooleanBinding done` becomes eligible for garbage collection and with the actual function gets collected before the call back function can be made.